# Excel If statement for setting cell drop down box and hide

Tags: excel, if-statement, return-value, addition

I have a spreadsheet that tracks tasks with drop down boxes that include the values B, G ,Y, A, and N/A. The number of each status is calculated at the top of the sheet through a count if statement.

I am hoping to add in another drop down box above each section using the same as the above. So you can select N/A for a team. 
When selecting the N/A for the team I need a section of rows to also be set to N/A and hide the lines.

I am struggling to understand what I should be adding to set the cells to N/A - Please can someone help.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Range("G13") = "N/A" Then
```

**Set cells E14-E22 TO N/A and hide rows 14 - 22**

```
    'Range("14:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True'


    Else
    Range("14:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If
```

End Sub

Trigger cells details  are below

Target Trigger Cell G13 
Cell Range Row 14 - 22

Target Trigger Cell G23
Cell Range Row 24

Target Trigger Cell g 25
Cell Range Row 26 - 27

Target Trigger Cell G28 
Cell Range Row 29 - 30

Target Trigger Cell G31
Cell Range Row 32 - 34

Target Trigger Cell G35 
Cell Range Row 36 - 38

Target Trigger Cell G39 
Cell Range Row 30 - 41

Target Trigger Cell G42
Cell Range Row 43 - 44

Target Trigger Cell G45
Cell Range Row 46 - 49

Target Trigger Cell G50 
Cell Range Row 51 -54

Target Trigger Cell G55 
Cell Range Row 56 - 57

Target Trigger Cell G58
Cell Range Row 59 - 61

Target Trigger Cell G62
Cell Range Row 63 - 68

Target Trigger Cell G69
Cell Range Row  70 - 83

Target Trigger Cell G84 
Cell Range Row 85 - 87

Target Trigger Cell G88
Cell Range Row 89 - 97

Target Trigger Cell G98 
Cell Range Row 99 - 104

Target Trigger Cell G105
Cell Range Row 106 - 111

Target Trigger Cell G112 
Cell Range Row 113 - 115

Target Trigger Cell G116 
Cell Range Row 117 - 118

Target Trigger Cell G119 
Cell Range Row 120 - 124

Target Trigger Cell G125
Cell Range Row 126 - 128

Target Trigger Cell G129
Cell Range Row 130 - 137

Target Trigger Cell G138 
Cell Range Row 139 - 145

Target Trigger Cell G146 
Cell Range Row 147

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger cell is G13, G23, G33, etc then,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing And _
           (Target.Row Mod 10) = 3 And _
           Target.Row >= 13 Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Target.Offset(1, -2).Resize(9, 1)
            If Target.Value2 = "N/A" Then
                .Value = "N/A"
                .EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                .Value = vbNullString
                .EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        End With
    End If
meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks the above is helpful. The target cells are not always 10 so for example the first one is G13 and the Second is G23 however the third is G25 so it changes. - Any ideas how I could include this in the code ? If needed I can provide a list of all of the target cells and what should be hidden.

Comment: Not without someway to identify the target trigger cell as well as the range below it to act upon.

Comment: If I could work that out could I simply do a load of if statements ? for example if I know that Target Trigger Cell is  G13 
and Cell Range Row is 14 - 22 would it be possible to do if G13 = N/A then Cells E14 - 22 are also N/A and hidden ?  Then do else if and carry on with the next one ?

Comment: You would probably be better off with If ... then ... elseif ... then ... elseif ... end if.

Comment: Ok thanks - Any ideas how I get the Value of the Cell to become N/A ? I think I was close to the If ... then ... elseif ... then ... elseif ... end if in the original question just not sure how to set the Cells E14 - E22 to change to include the value "N/A"

Comment: For G13, `Target.Offset(1, -2).Resize(9, 1).value = "N/A"` (as I've done above)

Comment: Sorry stupid question how would I change that to work for the others ? What does the 1,-2 and 9, 1 actually mean ?